# UPnP for iPhone

Tags: iphone

What free upnp library would you recommend for iPhone development? It has to support control point features and allow to serve files off from iPhone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an open source project on Sourcefourge that will do this called [CyberLink for C](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clinkobjc/)

It is written in C which integrates with Objective-C easily, but they provide Objective-C wrappers also. With it you can create UPnP applications easily with Objective-C on Mac OS X.

This is not to be confused with the Cyberlink DVD player software. They are two completely different things.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this one: http://code.google.com/p/upnpx/

Comment: Discontinued. So I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: might be discontinued, but works fairly well!

Comment: AFAIK it has support for control **point/client** only. But the OP also wants _to serve files off from iPhone_.

Answer (score 2):

There is also MiniUPNP, http://miniupnp.free.fr/ which is open source. It is in C and written for POSIX, no idea if that works on the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

This is another vote against CyberLink. Lots of bugs, basic functionality is missing, and way too slow on mobile devices (I think the main performance problem is that it is designed around DOM based XML parsing rather than SAX based).

I have heard a lot of people mention using the Platinum UPnP library, but so far I haven't found any Obj-C wrappers for it. I may just bite the bullet and do that soon.

Does anyone else know of a Platinum Objective-C wrapper?

Comment: I started a Obj-C wrapper object layer myself -> https://github.com/gravitymobile/Platinum-UPnP It's actually a mirror of the full library with the Obj-C wrappers added. At the moment, it is heavily geared toward UPnP-AV Control Point features, and the API still pretty rough, but it works well. In general I think Platinum is the best bet for doing UPnP-AV stuff, but it is way to heavyweight to use for simple UPnP IGD protocol you'll want something more lightweight (like MiniUPnP maybe...)

Comment: I guess this is the right URL. fonetik's link does no longer seem to work: https://github.com/gravitymobile/Platinum

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently playing with the CyberLink, and it's loaded with bugs :(
I think that the Portable UPnP should be better, as it's actively maintained (although the last release was several years ago, the subversion repository is constantly updated).
As you asked this question almost year ago, I wonder how things turned out.

Comment: Do you mean Platinum UPnP SDK?

Comment: No. http://pupnp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ohNet](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet).  It contains both control point and device stacks, is available under a BSD license and has C++ and C APIs which are usable on iPhone.

(Disclaimer: I have contributed to this project)

Comment: It seems interesting, but I 'd like a sample on how to open/close a port forwarding (NAT) using it...

Comment: Assuming you know which UPnP service(s) to use for NAT, you could use the control point tests for [C](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet/blob/master/OpenHome/Net/Bindings/C/ControlPoint/Tests/TestProxyC.cpp) and [C++](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet/blob/master/OpenHome/Net/Bindings/Cpp/ControlPoint/Tests/TestInvocationStd.cpp) for examples of how to use ohNet.