# Which UPnP libraries for iOS are available to communicate with UPnP enabled devices over the local WiFi network?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, upnp

I have found [upnpx](http://code.google.com/p/upnpx/), a static OS X & iOS UPnP library written in Cocoa (UPnP) and C++ (SSDP). Is there something easier to use written or wrapped in Objective-C?

We need to communicate with an UPnP device like this:

1) Scan the network for available devices of a certain type. iOS device stays connected to existing WiFi network but simply scans for available UPnP devices.

2) Request their current state.

3) Send them a command to modify their state.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPnP for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136072/upnp-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I used this library to implement an IP camera detector:

https://code.google.com/p/upnpx/

The project is discontinued, but still it works fairly well and is the only solution I could find...

Comment: https://github.com/fkuehne/upnpx is the new location for this project, and it is NOT discontinued :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fkuehne/upnpx

Is the new fork for the google project. and it is still active!