# UPnP library for iOS, binary light switch

Tags: ios, xcode, upnp

I'm intermediary at Objective-C and I'm current trying to make an app that control an device using UPnP, the app is a control point and the device is a Binary Light Switch.
For UPnP I have to parse XML and I'm using [UPnPx library](https://code.google.com/p/upnpx/) but it seems a little old, because I don't stop getting those LLVM 5.0 error, and can't use Auto Layout. I've searched a lot for others libraries but the one that seems more easy is UPnPx. Could you guys help me with some example code for binary light switch or other libraries? Thx!

Comment: See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1136072/311966) for a list of other UPnP stacks that work on iOS

Comment: I've already tried..it's also an old post..2009 =/

Comment: That doesn't mean that the answers aren't still valid.  Some of the answers point to hobbyist code but others provide links to stacks that are actively maintained and in commercial use.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are few well-known UPnP libraries can be easily integrated into your iOS project.

## [CyberLink4C](https://github.com/cybergarage/CyberLink4C)

It is implemented by C, but with Objective-C wrapper.
Here are some examples https://github.com/cybergarage/CyberLink4C/tree/master/examples.

## [Platinum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/platinum/)

It is implemented by C++, with Objective-C wrapper, too.
Beware, it is a dual license library, GPL or commercial, read http://www.plutinosoft.com/platinum/ for detail information.

## [UPnPx](https://code.google.com/p/upnpx/)

It is implemented by Objective-C, but the performance of searching device is poor.